# Как вернуть не-String объект из JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

Имеется обычный `JComboBox`  и кнопка `JButton`, по нажатию которой необходимо вернуть выбранный из списка элемент. В качестве элементов `JComboBox` там содержится список элементов класса `Item`, к котором определено некое поле `private String name`.

При отображении в `JComboBox` элементы записаны в виде `pack.pack1.Item@######` , т.е. как я понимаю, используется метод `toString`.
Если использовать метод `getSelectedItem()` из `JComboBox` то при нажатии кнопки получаем на выходе элемент класса `Item`.

Такой подход не совсем подходит, т.к. отображение не совсем корректно выглядит.
Если же в классе `Item` переопределять `toString()`, и в нем прописывать `getName()`, то при использовании `getSelectedItem()` получаем объект типа `String`.

Как можно решить данную проблемы: чтобы при отображении приписывалось содержимое поля `name`, а при нажатии на кнопку получали объект класса `Item`? 
Была идея как-то через `Map` попробовать, но может есть какое-то более хорошее решение?

```
public class ChooseHashtagsPanel extends JPanel {

private JComboBox comboBox;

private HashtagController controller;

public ChooseHashtagsPanel(HashtagController hashtagController){
    super();
    this.controller = hashtagController;
    this.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Choose hashtags"));
    this.setBounds(20, 240, 340, 70);
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Choose tag");

    //TODO set mapping of hashtags in (completed)
    //TODO Change dummy
    Searchable<Hashtag, String> s = new HashtagSearchable(hashtagController);
    comboBox = new AutocompleteJComboBox(s);
    JButton button = new JButton("Choose Hashtag");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Choosen: " + ((Hashtag)comboBox.getSelectedItem()).getTagname());
        }
    });

    this.add(label);
    this.add(comboBox);
    this.add(button);
}

}
```

Сам ComboBox:

```
public class AutocompleteJComboBox extends JComboBox {

    private final Searchable<Hashtag, String> searchable;

    public AutocompleteJComboBox(final Searchable<Hashtag, String> searchable1){
        super();
        this.searchable = searchable1;
        setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
        setEditable(true);
        Component c = getEditor().getEditorComponent();
        if ( c instanceof JTextComponent){
            final JTextComponent tc = (JTextComponent)c;
            tc.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                }
                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println("ACTION!insertUpdate " + arg0.getDocument().toString());
                    update();
                }
                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println("ACTION!removeUpdate " + arg0.getDocument().toString());
                    update();
                }
                public void update(){
                    //perform separately, as listener conflicts between the editing component
                    //and JComboBox will result in an IllegalStateException due to editing
                    //the component when it is locked.
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("public void run() text " + tc.getText());
                            java.util.List<Hashtag> founds = new ArrayList<Hashtag>(searchable.search(tc.getText()));
                            Set<Hashtag> foundSet = new HashSet<Hashtag>();

                            for ( Hashtag s : founds ){
                                foundSet.add(s);
                            }
                            //Collections.sort(founds);//sort alphabetically
                            setEditable(false);
                            removeAllItems();
                            //if founds contains the search text, then only add once.
                            if ( !foundSet.contains( tc.getText().toLowerCase()) ){
                                addItem( tc.getText() );
                            }
                            for (Hashtag s : founds) {
                                addItem(s);
                            }
                            setEditable(true);
                            setPopupVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            //When the text component changes, focus is gained
            //and the menu disappears. To account for this, whenever the focus
            //is gained by the JTextComponent and it has searchable values, we show the popup.
            tc.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println("public void focusGained");
                    if (tc.getText().length() > 0) {
                        setPopupVisible(true);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println("public void focusLost");
                }
            });
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException("Editing component is not a JTextComponent!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: проблема понятна, но можно чуть-чуть кода?

Comment: Swing сильно устарел, в следующий раз попробуй освоить javafx, он будет поновее, получше.

Comment: @АлексейПересторонин, да, как раз думал между swing и fx, но просто swing это считай как азы, поэтому решил остановиться на это библиотеке)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переопределяйте метод toString() в классе, который помещаете в JComboBox, чтобы он возвращал то, что вам нужно(name). Типизировать JComboBox не нужно дженериком. 
При вызове нажатия на кнопку вызывайте просто каст:

```
...............
class A{
   public String name;
   public String descr;

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return name;
   }
}
...................
A a1 = new A();
a1.name("Элкемент 1");
a1.descr("Нечто");
jComboBox1.addItem(a1);
...............
A a = (A) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
System.out.println(a.descr)
.....................
```

Где А - ваш класс. И получите в итоге весь объект. А отображение должно быть в порядке.

Полный пример

```
public class TestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private class A {

        public String name;
        public String desrc;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates new form TestFrame
     */
    public TestFrame() {
        initComponents();
        jComboBox1.removeAllItems();;
        A a1 = new A();
        a1.name = "Test";
        a1.desrc = "Hello";
        jComboBox1.addItem(a1);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 162, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(83, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addContainerGap(266, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        System.out.println(((A) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()).desrc);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: так там же ClassCastException вылетать будет. Это был второй мой описанный вариант.

Comment: Добавил полный пример. У меня не вылетает. Попробуйте скомпилировать и запустить у себя

Comment: По всем видимости ошибка была в том, что setModel для JComboBox не использовался. Подправил у себя ошибки нет.

Comment: Хорошо, что получилось)

Comment: Странно, но после того, как вроде бы все исправно заработало, запустил еще раз а в итоге опять получил эксепшн) странно как-то.. да и похоже, что дело не в setModel, а вот понять в чем именно не могу

Comment: похоже необходимо было поменять строку 
`public class AutocompleteJComboBox extends JComboBox`
на 
`public class AutocompleteJComboBox extends JComboBox<Hashtag>`

хотя все равно не совсем понятно почему у тебя без этого работало, а у меня нет)